# C# Roslyn Analyzer Get Defenition/Implementation of Methods/Constructors/Etc

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing Code Analysis Rule that should check next:

1. If class is derived from `IInterface`
2. If so, check that it contains method `MyMethod`
3. Does this method calls `Foo`?

Basically, every class that derives from `IInterface` must have `MyMethod` and it should call `Foo`.

That is really simple to achieve, I will simply register my analyzator as a `SyntaxKind.ClassDeclarationSyntax`. There I will check if class is derived from `IInterface`, and check that there's `MyMethod`.

BUT, what if `MyMethod` calls, lets say, `SomeFunction` that calls `Foo`? So, `MyMethod` doesn't call `Foo` directly but it calls `SomeFunction` which calls that what we need.

The best way, in my mind, is simply iterate over all method calls/object creations/etc. in `MyMethod` and then go to the definition of each of those methods/constructors/etc. and search for `Foo` call (Yes, this is might be heavy for the performance, but still I need this (or maybe you can recommend some other way)).

But here's the problem and my main question:

> How can I get the definition/implementation of the Symbol that I hit?

I've tried `SymbolFinder` and all of its methods, like, `FindDefinition`, `FindImplementation`, etc. But this doesn't work (I don't know if it is actually works, it's just I don't have `Solution`).

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What if it calls out to an external assembly (referenced but not sourced) that contains a method that happens to call `Foo`? What about `if (random.Next() < 0) Foo()`, does that count even though it will never call `Foo`? What if it calls `MyVirtualMethod() { Foo(); }` which is overridden in a derived class so it no longer calls `Foo`? Just playing devil's advocate; these cases may never occur in your code base or else you can lay down simple rules to cover them, but they're still worth considering because bad analysis is often worse than none.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, to be honest, it's not that's important, because this rule is like a guide. `if (random.Next() < 0) Foo()`, yes, this considers as a call, as well as `MyVirtualMethod() { Foo(); }`. I don't really mind all of this. I just provided information, but I really want to know how to get definition/implementation.